# The actual value is stored in pstr ,but how the value is stored in array "WORD"

Tags: c

i have a doubt how the value is stored in "WORD",since the PStr contains the actual output.?

since the lowercase to uppercase letters are stored in Pstr ,then how in printf it is given as "WORD". could anyone pls. explain?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define CASE 5

int main (void)
{
    char word[50];
    char *pstr = word;
    char mask;

    printf("enter a word");
    fgets(word,sizeof(word)-1,stdin);
    printf("original string : %s\n",word);

    mask = 1<<CASE;
    mask =~mask;

    while (*pstr != '\n')

    {
        *pstr = *pstr & mask;
        pstr++;
    }

printf("modified string: %s\n",word);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`pstr` is a pointer to `word` so they can be used interchangeably (you should not modify `word` however).

In C, when you declare an array, the variable of the array is a pointer to the array.

Comment: Arrays and pointers are quite different things in C. An array name can be *converted* to a pointer to the first element of the array (there are no pointers to arrays in C; e.g. `char[]*` is not a legal type, there is no `(char[]*)` cast, etc.).